# Rocket needed to send 100 gram of mass to outer space?

Tags: astronomy, orbital-motion, rocket-science

What kind of rocket would be needed to send 100 gr of mass to outer space?

The mass can be moulded in any shape, but it would need not raise above 40 °C of temperature during the process.

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge there aren't any platforms currently targeting a payload that small.

The only platform I'm aware of targeting satellites that small is [CubeSat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CubeSat) which has a 1.33 kg mass limit and 10x10x10 cm volume limit. However CubeSats are launched as secondary payloads on larger rockets being used for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rockets that would allow something to orbit with that small of a mass. As @DanNeely mentioned, the best you can do is Cubesats, which are typically very low on the pecking order.

If you just want to get a 100 gram mass to touch space, then look into a [sounding rocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sounding_rocket). They won't orbit, but you could at least get something to space, and that might be good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If orbiting is not crucial then you can also consider near-space balloons like [Project Icarus](http://space.1337arts.com/)'s.